# How can I find if a row exists in a file and add a column with the filename using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to find if a row in a file already exists in another file, and, in that case, add a column with the filename.

File1:

```
 CHROM  POS REF ALT
 chr1   10  T   A
 chr1   12  T   G
 chr1   12  T   C
```

File2:

```
 CHROM  POS REF ALT
 chr1   12  T   C
 chr1   13  A   T
```

I want to check if any row in file2 is in file1.

***Expected output:***

```
 CHROM  POS REF ALT
 chr1   10  T   A
 chr1   12  T   G
 chr1   12  T   C   file2
```

I've tried with this code:

```
 `awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR
 {
   seen[$0];next
  }($0 in seen)
 {
   delete seen[$0]
 };
   END{
    for (x in seen);$(NF+1)="file";print
       }
  {print}' OFS="\t" file2  file1`
```

But this is not working as expected. This is what I'm getting:

```
 CHROM  POS REF ALT
  chr1  10  T   A
  chr1  12  T   G
  chr1  12  T   C
  chr1  12  T   C   file2
```

How could I delete the duplicated row? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1 && FNR==NR{
  print
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]=FILENAME
  next
}
FNR>1{
  print $0,$0 in a?OFS a[$0]:""
}'  file2  file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
CHROM  POS REF ALT
chr1   10  T   A 
chr1   12  T   G 
chr1   12  T   C  file2
```

NOTE: In case Input_files are TAB delimited and we need output in TAB delimited form too then add a `BEGIN` section after `awk` like `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}....`

Comment: It works but it also add the filename in the header. I have to do this with many files in a directory, will it work in a loop? It could happend that a row exists in two files, so in that case it will change the number of columns

Comment: now I'm getting the same as in my post. EDIT: I get the output you've posted

Comment: Perfect,now it works as expected. Than you very much for the fast!

Comment: @Marta_ma, Keep learning and keep posting on this GREAT site SO,cheers.

Comment: Could you help me with my other issue? I have a directory with many files that I have to compare always with file1 and if a row exists in multiple files, I need to append all the file names @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @Marta_ma, IMHO I would suggest you to open a new thread and mention in there all details clearly, we will try to guide and help you there, cheers.