# Find if a row exists in a file and add a column with the filename using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Here I asked the same question and get a correct answer: [How can I find if a row exists in a file and add a column with the filename using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753300/how-can-i-find-if-a-row-exists-in-a-file-and-add-a-column-with-the-filename-usin)

I open this new thread, as @RavinderSingh13 suggested, giving more details.

I have a file like this as database (db_file.txt):

```
  CHROM  POS REF ALT
  chr1   10  T   A
  chr1   12  T   G
  chr1   12  T   C
```

And a large number of files in which I need to check if a row is already in the database file. In case a row exists, I have to add a newcolumn with the file name.

An example with two files

file1:

```
  CHROM  POS REF ALT          
  chr1   10  T   A                                   
  chr1   13  T   C
```

file2:

```
    CHROM  POS REF ALT
     chr1   12  T   G  
     chr1   10  T   A
```

***Expected output:***

```
  CHROM  POS REF ALT
  chr1   10  T   A   file1   file2
  chr1   12  T   G   file2
  chr1   12  T   C
```

I'm trying to do with this code but I don't get what I need:

```
 for i in `ls directory`;do

      awk 'FNR==1 && FNR==NR{print;next}

      FNR==NR{a[$0]=FILENAME;next}FNR>1{

      print $0,$0 in a?OFS a[$0]:""}' $i $directory/db_file.txt

  done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash records plus how many times they've been seen with filenames they come from in an array while reading `file1`, `file2` etc, and use it for updating records while processing `db_file.txt`. `$1=$1` is there for squeezing spaces, drop it if unnecessary.

```
awk '{$1=$1} FILENAME!="db_file.txt"{a[$0,++n[$0]]=FILENAME;next}
FNR>1{r=$0;for(i=1;i<=n[r];++i) $(NF+1)=a[r,i]}1' file{1,2} db_file.txt
```

Comment: Hi @oguzismail ! Thank you very much for your answer and your help with my awk issues. What does ++n[$0] do?

Comment: @Marta_ma you're welcome. it counts duplicates; increases `n[$0]` by 1 for each duplicate, so that we know how many files have the same record

Comment: I'm trying to run the script in a for loop because I have multiple directories and files, and it doesn't work, it doesn't output anything... Do you see something wrong in the code? All the variables are previously defined  in my script.   `for i in `ls $TSO`;do   awk -F="\t" '{$1=$1} FILENAME!="variants_database.txt"{a[$0,++n[$0]]=FILENAME;next}
  FNR>1{r=$0;for(i=1;i<=n[r];++i) $(NF+1)=a[r,i]}1' OFS="\t" $TSO/$i/$vcf/*raw.vcf $DB  done`

Comment: A problem with quotation marks and asterik. Actually, it's partially solved. I can't use variables to define the path to the files, but replacing the variables by its value, it works